# How to open a JFrame behind the main JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Everytime I open a JFrame from my main JFrame It appears in front of my main JFrame. I know how to open it in different positions of the screen but that doesn't solve the problem.

I have no idea how to open it behind the main JFrame.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  *"I have no idea how to open it behind the main JFrame."*  I don't see that as a bad thing, given it would be confusing to the end user.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [toBack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toBack%28%29)  method after `setVisible(true)` method to open `New JFrame`  behind the main JFrame.

Example code:

```
newFrame.setVisible(true);
newFrame.toBack();
```

Comment: It would need to be tested, but under some os's, this might not work

Comment: @MadProgrammer Tested with windows 10 and windows 8 but as javadoc says it might not work on all platform.

Comment: I think it's the right approach (or the best we have available, just need to beware ;))

Comment: It works on windows 7 but It doesn't have the desired effect, surrounding the JFrame opening block with  `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` and `setAlwaysOnTop(false)` It was the best option. Even though It's quite bungler.

Comment: @YassinHH because I thought that might suit better with the next person looking for the question I made. Still thank you very much.